# Dropdown menu <li> elements not full width as parent

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a personal website and trying to implement dropdown behavior on some of my navbar elements. Currently, my relevant CSS and HTML for my navbar is:

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content {
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/wantlists">Wantlists</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Hover here</a>
      <ul class=dropdown-content>
        <li><a href="#">Test!</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Longer title</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- End parent dropdown -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

only span around half the width of the parent li and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it span the full width. Below is a screenshot of part of my navbar when hovering over the "Hover here" element. I'd like the gray background of the "Test!" and "Longer title" sub-li elements to expand left to the width of the white background of the "Hover here" element. I've tried a bunch of different things and have explored similar questions, but none of the answers I have seen have solved my problem

[image: Dropdown]

I was able to get the gray background I desired by adding a background-color rule to .dropdown-content, but then my next step would be to change the background color of an individual li element on hover within the dropdown, and then I'm back to only being able to highlight part of that li area, so that's not exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap Framework ?

Comment: I did use Bootstrap to start, but I've customized some of it since then to fit my needs. The div with the dropdown-content class and child elements to that is code of my own, as well as all of the CSS I shared

Comment: if you want to increase the sub menu to 100% then apply `.dropdown-content { width:100%; }`

Comment: That does not work for me

Comment: @Hollywood I think you don't need to add custom css to get dropdown menu on Bootstrap since it has provided it for you.

Comment: Dropdown nav wasn't supported in the template I grabbed from Bootstrap, so I've been attempting to customize myself. I'd rather not add even more Bootstrap because I find I often only need one of the many rules they provide and it becomes quite extraneous and hard to find specific rules I'd like to change

Comment: @Hollywood please use this class  .dropdown-content
{
    padding-left: 0px;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the `<li>` fullwidth but not the `<a>`, you won't be able to click on the whole menu item. Here's some code to get you pointed in the right direction.

Main things to note:

- Remove padding for `.dropdown-content`
- Made `.dropdown-content` the fullwidth of the parent `li`
- Repeated last note on `li` and `a`
- Made a `:hover` class for the `a`

```css
.nav li {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
}
.dropdown-content {
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 0; /* moves the dropdown to matche left alignment of menu item */
      min-width: 100%; /* makes the dropdown container the same width as the menu item */
}
.dropdown-content li {
      width: 100%; /* makes the dropdown menu item the same width as the container */
}
.dropdown-content a {
      display: block;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      background-color: #e6e6e6;
      width: 100%;  /* makes the anchor tag the same width as the dropdown menu item */
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #dddddd; /* add a hover color the the anchor tag instead of the li */
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="/wantlists">Wantlists</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Hover here</a>
           <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#">Test!</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer title</a></li>
           </ul>
      </li> <!-- End parent dropdown -->
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working well for me. I don't fully understand why this works but my original CSS doesn't, but I'll study the two to compare and hopefully it will become clearer. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Hollywood I added some comments to the code for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to size the link/a href not the li, and you forgot quotes around the list class "dropdown-content" in the html. I've added a global selector to simulate a css reset just to show list styling and spacing properly:

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
      /*display: none;*/
      position: absolute;
}
ul.nav {
      list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-content a {
      padding: 1em;
      background-color: #e6e6e6;
      display: block;
}
ul.dropdown-content {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-content li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="/wantlists">Wantlists</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Hover here</a>
           <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#">Test!</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer title</a></li>
           </ul>
      </li> <!-- End parent dropdown -->
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following css

```
.dropdown-content
{
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

This will works.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
      /*display: none;*/
      position: absolute;
}
ul.nav {
      list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-content a {
      padding: 1em;
      background-color: #e6e6e6;
      display: block;
}
ul.dropdown-content {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-content li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="/wantlists">Wantlists</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Hover here</a>
           <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#">Test!</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer title</a></li>
           </ul>
      </li> <!-- End parent dropdown -->
</ul>
</div>
```

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
      /*display: none;*/
      position: absolute;
}
ul.nav {
      list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-content a {
      padding: 1em;
      background-color: #e6e6e6;
      display: block;
}
ul.dropdown-content {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-content li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="/wantlists">Wantlists</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Hover here</a>
           <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#">Test!</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer title gre gre gẻ gẻ gre gé</a></li>
           </ul>
      </li> <!-- End parent dropdown -->
</ul>
</div>
```